# PHP trying to set category by keywords no error and empty tags

Tags: php, xml, keyword

I trying to make XML feed with product categories by specific keywords in their names and getting these data from .csv everything okay.. Just the one problem is the assigning categories into xml feeds..

Link of the .csv catalog: https://ociostock.gesio.be/dyndata/exportaciones/csvzip/catalog_1_51_54_2_38849185cc8487a046bd2bf4a46de0ed_csv_plain.csv

The assigning condition:

```
$catalog_name = 'catalog.csv';
$file_url = 'https://ociostock.gesio.be/dyndata/exportaciones/csvzip/catalog_1_51_54_2_38849185cc8487a046bd2bf4a46de0ed_csv_plain.csv';
file_put_contents($catalog_name, fopen($file_url, 'r'));

$categories = [
    'facemask' => 'mascarillas', 
    'mascarilla' => 'mascarillas', 
    'mask' => 'mascarillas', 
    'juego' => 'juguetes',
    'playdoh' => 'juguetes',
    'puzzle' => 'juguetes',
    'monopoly' => 'juguetes',
    'notebook' => 'papeleria',
    'pencil' => 'papeleria',
    'pencil case' => 'papeleria',
    'bag' => 'otros',
    'schoolbag' => 'otros',
    'rucksack' => 'otros',
    'quokka' => 'otros',
    'mug' => 'otros',
    'bottle' => 'otros',
    'towel' => 'otros',
    'funko' => 'colleccionables',   
];

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->encoding = 'utf-8';



$dom->xmlVersion = '1.0';



$dom->formatOutput = true;



$xml_file_name = 'products.xml';

$root = $dom->createElement('SHOP');


$flag = true;     

$h = fopen($catalog_name, 'r');
while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 30000, ';')) !== FALSE)
{  
    if($flag) {
        $flag = false;
        continue;
    }
        
    $item_node = $dom->createElement('SHOPITEM');
    
    $name = $data[3];
    $description = $data[5];
    $price = $data[8] * 1.30 * 1.21;
    $rounded_price = round($price, 2);
    $active = $data[13];
    $stock = $data[15];
    $ean = $data[19];
    $img_url = $data[22];
    $units_per_order = $data[24]; 
    
    $trimmed_ean = utf8_decode($ean);
   
    if ($units_per_order != "1") {
        $active = "0"; 
        $stock = "0";
    }
   
    if ($active != "1" || $units_per_order != "1") {
        continue; 
    }
    
    $category = $categories[$name] ?? '';
    var_dump($category);
   
    
    $item_node->appendChild($dom->createElement('PRODUCTNAME',  htmlspecialchars($name)));
    $item_node->appendChild($dom->createElement('DESCRIPTION',  htmlspecialchars($description)));
    $item_node->appendChild($dom->createElement('PRICE_VAT',  strval($rounded_price)));
    $item_node->appendChild($dom->createElement('IMG_URL',  strval($img_url)));
    $item_node->appendChild($dom->createElement('EAN',  strval($trimmed_ean)));
    $item_node->appendChild($dom->createElement('STOCK',  strval($stock)));
    $item_node->appendChild($dom->createElement('ACTIVE',  strval($active)));
    $item_node->appendChild($dom->createElement('CATEGORYTEXT', htmlspecialchars($category)));        
    
    
    $root->appendChild($item_node);
    
} 
    
fclose($h); 
  

$dom->appendChild($root);



$dom->save($xml_file_name);
```

and here I appending the function which making CATEGORYTEXT with name of category from condition block above.. So, if some keyword is in $name variable then it should set $category variable by condition..

But every product in my XML feed http://tiendadejuguetes.eu/wp-content/cron/products.xml has empty CATEGORYTEXT tag as you can see, for example the first product has keyword 'bottle' in name so why the CATEGORYTEXT tag is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions don't work. See:

```
$name = 'facemask';
var_dump(
    strpos($name, 'facemask' || 'mascarilla' || 'mask')
);
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
```

This is because your argument evaluates to true:

```
var_dump('facemask' || 'mascarilla' || 'mask');
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

I suggest using a map. But with each category allowing for several substring inside the `$name` this is a little more complex so let's define a little class that encapsulates the logic:

```
class CategoryMatcher {
    
    private $_map;
    
    public function __construct(array $map) {
        $this->_map = $map;
    }
    
    public function match(string $text): ?string {
        $text = strtolower($text);
        foreach ($this->_map as $category => $subStrings) {
            if ($this->containsOneOf($text, $subStrings)) {
                return $category;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    
    private function containsOneOf(string $text, array $subStrings): bool {
        foreach ($subStrings as $subString) {
            if (FALSE !== strpos($text, $subString)) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}

$matcher = new CategoryMatcher(
    [
        'doll' => ['figure'],
        'clothes' => ['t-shirt'],
        'stationary' => ['notebook', 'pencil case']
    ]
);
    

$examples = [
   'assorted A5 notebook',
   'premium adult t-shirt',
   'adult premium t-shirt',
   'Daisy figure',
   'Cars Pencil case',
   'Cars Pole Gym bag 35cm'
];
foreach ($examples as $example) {
   echo $example, ': ', $matcher->match($example), "\n";  
}
```

Output:

```
assorted A5 notebook: stationary
premium adult t-shirt: clothes
adult premium t-shirt: clothes
Daisy figure: doll
Cars Pencil case: stationary
Cars Pole Gym bag 35cm:
```

Additionally, be careful with the second argument of `DOMdocument::createElement()` - it breaks if your variable contains an `&` that is not part of an valid entity. Better use `DOMNode::$textContent`.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('CATEGORYTEXT'))
  ->textContent = 'mascarillas';
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CATEGORYTEXT>mascarillas</CATEGORYTEXT>
```

Comment: Hi, by following your instructions.. every product throws me this: string(0) "" so I edited the code to check.. So, where is the problem by your opinion?

Comment: If you include a sample of the CSV data in your question I might be able to answer that.

Comment: I think problem will be in the condition because when I had only one condition if - else block which checked only the mascarilla categories it worked well but I appended full code + link to .csv catalog.